# MapBox Snap Map Cities boundaries update for SnapChat

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, snapchat, mapbox-ios

I would like to know how we can contact Mapbox team to correct cities boundaries that are not correctly defined. We tried in Snap Map settings MapBox option but that redirects to their main website. Also we found its using openstreetmap and we updated the boundaries there but those data are not synchronized with Snap Map.

Also raised a question to technical support team but not receiving any update and in their auto reply its mentioned to use "mapbox" tag in StackOverflow to get response..  Hence I am requesting here for help .. I would appreciate if we have direct way of communication to fix this boundaries issue and we will use proper communication channel for such requests. Thanks